# Redirect one or more URL to just one, with regular expressions

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewrite, 301-redirect

In my website I have some pages that are reachable by two urls:

- .../page
- .../parameter/page

In order to optimize the website for the search engines, I have to redirect all .../page urls to .../parameter/page urls.

How can I reach that modifying the file .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the redirect perform with the desired behavior, implement a rewrite rule similar to the one included below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/(special|cases|which|should|be|excluded)/) [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) http://www.example.com/parameter/$1 [L,R=301]
```

A solution to the more specific problem mentioned in the [comments](https://serverfault.com/questions/462101/redirect-one-or-more-url-to-just-one-with-regular-expressions/462118#462118) (i.e., redirecting all pages that do not have a specific context to use the 'en' context) would be something similar to the following rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/(en|it|de|fr)/) [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) http://www.example.com/en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note that any additional language directories which the rewrite rule should not apply to will need to be added to the escape clause in the RewriteCond.

Additionally, once this has been put in place, a graceful will need to be issued on Apache in order to pick up the changes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But "page" means every page without a parameter. In this case, parameters are language acronims (en,it,de,fr,...). I don't know if now I've been very clear.

Comment: Maybe I have not been accurate. I'm sorry, I would create a more general post, useful to other cases. Here are my particular needs: I have a multilanguage website and the default language pages  are reachable with "domain/page" and also "domain/en/page". The pages in the other languages are reachable just through the language folder ("domain/de/page"). So I want that every "domain/page" redirect to the respective "domain/en/page".

Comment: No worries -- thanks for the additional information.  Just to clarify, do you only want the domain/page combinations to redirect only to the 'en' context (e.g., /info -> /en/info, /about -> /en/about, etc.)?  If so, I'll update the answer to reflect this behavior.

Comment: Yes, exactly! Of course I have pages in other languages (/it/info, /it/about, /de/info, /de/about, etc) that don't have to be touched by the rules.

Comment: The answer has been updated to reflect both the general case and your specific scenario.